# More than one ajax form on wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

i have already one Ajax form on my wordpress website. Now, i need a second one. So i duplicate the function in Function.php. But it does'nt work.

The first form is contact. The second one is inscription. The first one work great. 
But for the second one, nothing happen when i try to send...

Here my code.

```
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_contact', '_ajax_contact' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_contact', '_ajax_contact' );

    function _ajax_contact() {

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  On vérifie le nonce de sécurité
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

check_ajax_referer( 'ajax_contact_nonce', 'security' );


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Protection des variables
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

$subject = wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['subject'] ); // Sujet du message
$name = wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['name'] ); // Nom de l'expéditeur
$sender = sanitize_email( $_POST['email'] ); // Adresse e-mail de l'expéditeur
$message = nl2br( stripslashes( wp_kses( $_POST['message'], $GLOBALS['allowedtags'] ) ) );


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Gestion des headers
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'FROM : ' . $name . ' <' . $sender .'>' . "\r\n";


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Gestion du message
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

ob_start();
include( get_template_directory() . '/inc/mail/contact.php' );
$mail = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Envoie de l'e-mail
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


// Support d'un contenu HTML dans l'email
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', create_function('', 'return "text/html";') );

if( wp_mail( 'emailtest@gmail.com', '[subject] Contact', $mail, $headers ) ) {

    // Tout est ok, on avertit l'utilisateur
    wp_send_json( 'success' );

}
else {

    // Il y a une erreur avec le mail, on avertit l'utilisateur
    wp_send_json( 'error' );
        }


     }  

               /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Second form
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

  add_action( 'wp_ajax_inscription', '_ajax_inscription' );
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_inscription', '_ajax_inscription' );

  function _ajax_inscription() {

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  On vérifie le nonce de sécurité
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

check_ajax_referer( 'ajax_inscription_nonce', 'security' );


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Protection des variables
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
$subject = wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['subject'] ); // Sujet du message
$name = wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['name'] ); // Nom de l'expéditeur
$sender = sanitize_email( $_POST['email'] ); // Adresse e-mail de l'expéditeur
$message = nl2br( stripslashes( wp_kses( $_POST['message'], $GLOBALS['allowedtags'] ) ) );


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Gestion des headers
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'FROM : ' . $name . ' <' . $sender .'>' . "\r\n";


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Gestion du message
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

ob_start();
include( get_template_directory() . '/inc/mail/contact.php' );
$mail = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Envoie de l'e-mail
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


// Support d'un contenu HTML dans l'email
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', create_function('', 'return "text/html";') );

if( wp_mail( 'testemail@gmail.com', $subject, $mail, $headers ) ) {

    // Tout est ok, on avertit l'utilisateur
    wp_send_json( 'success' );

}
else {

    // Il y a une erreur avec le mail, on avertit l'utilisateur
    wp_send_json( 'error' );
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank for your answer, finally i have found another solution. The problem was not in this file..

It was on my form file. I forgot to change a value on the send button.

My mistake :

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="contact" />
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'ajax_inscription_nonce', 'security' ); ?>
            <input id="send-message" type="submit" value="Envoyer">
```

The good code

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="inscription" />
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'ajax_inscription_nonce', 'security' ); ?>
            <input id="send-message" type="submit" value="Envoyer">
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, the first thing I would try to do is to rename fields with `name='name'`. I coded a lot of forms and in almost every case, WP wouldn't post my forms, because it has reserved field with `name='name'`.

Also, activate [`WP_DEBUG`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) mode to show all errors and try to look for JavaScript errors with Firebug or the browser console.

Comment: Yes, unique field names is very important. . . . pherak, I did some formatting and rephrasing to be more in sync with what's used here, check the post history so you can learn from it. The guide [answer] has nice tips. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your corrections and useful tips brasofilo.